# What's the quickest and most reliable way to untarget your current target in GW2?

Tags: pc, guild-wars-2

Something that's been bothering me with the Guild Wars 2 controls is that there seems to be no way to deselect a target if you have a target selected. From looking at the list of control bindings there doesn't appear to be any way to do that.

In Guild Wars 1 there's a target self that's bind to the <kbd>f</kbd> key by default that can serve this purpose. However, GW2 does not seem to have a target self in the list of key binds either.

Is there even a way to do this that doesn't involve killing the target?

For those wondering why I want to have to no target selected during combat, many of the skills work slightly differently if a target is selected. In particular, many of the skills will go in the general direction you 'point' at if no target is selected. However, if a target ***is*** selected then the skills will go towards that target instead.

**Edit**: To recap, this question is about how to quickly, efficiently, accurately and reliably deselect your current target even in the thick of battle. While I appreciate the answers given by others, they all fail to meet this requirement in some way.

For example, <kbd>esc</kbd> is too overloaded to be reliable. That key services duty as menu popup, closes open ingame dialog boxes, stops your character from auto-running and probably others I forgot about.

The 'target nearest ally' doesn't work if there's no ally nearby. Even if there are, they have to be within a certain radius and your camera has to be facing them.

Clicking on screen is unreliable. Think about doing this in a massive WvW battle where everything is a graphical clusterfuck. If you should need to retreat then a reliable way to deselect a target is a must.

Comment: I think I remember one of the mouse clicks on the ground will cause you to untarget

Comment: ESC or click on the ground. ESC does work, if you have a target selected, it deselects it. If you don't have a target selected, it brings up the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the latest build, the quickest and most direct way to unselect a target is to bind the `Lock Autotarget` to an easily accessible key on your keyboard.

[image]

Despite what the tooltip might suggest, tapping the assigned key will untarget anything you are currently targeting.

Comment: So Lock Autotarget actually deselects? What misleading copy.

Comment: @DavidYell Yes it does. It only locks target as long as the key is held down. The moment the key is released, it deselects the target.

Answer (score 9):

Left-clicking on the ground is the most reliable way to deselect all targets.

<kbd>ESC</kbd> deselects any selected targets, but if nothing is selected you will bring up your menu (can be annoying mid-combat).

There is also a key binding to target the nearest ally, which will select yourself if no other allies are around. This is useful if you are having trouble finding a patch of ground to click on. This key is not assigned by default, so look for "Nearest Ally" under Targeting in [Options->Controls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Controls).

You can also select the next closest target using <kbd>TAB</kbd>, in case you do actually want to direct your spells towards a different enemy then the one you current have selected. Then again, a left-click on the target works more reliably if multiple targets are in view.

There is also a [Guild Wars 2 printable keyboard layout](http://cloudfront.guildwars2.com/QRC/GW2_QRC_NA_Digital.jpg) to help you visualize the default key bindings.

Comment: This is a very long way of saying ESC or left-click the ground.

Answer (score 3):

You can click on the ground to deselect your target.

Comment: Guess we'll find out. Last bwe is about to start :)

Comment: Yep, I can't wait! I started trying out a Mesmer a couple hours before the last one ended, and I was having fun. Can't wait to get back to it. Have to decide whether I want Warrior or Mesmer as my main.

Comment: In most MMO's this feature is called "Sticky Targeting" in this case you would want it disabled if it is and option and is turned on.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if I already have the option enabled or what, but I can click on the ground to untarget.

Comment: It's enabled by default, very convenient way to deselect everything.

Comment: @SadlyNot - Ah, yeah, they've changed the default since I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all MMOs I've played allow you to deselect your target with the ESC key. I seem to recall Guild Wars 1 doing this as well. Likely the same here.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. Pressing esc will just bring up the menu :(

Comment: That really is unfortunate. I use it so often elsewhere, I'd probably be lost without it.

Comment: not for me, if I have something selected and press ESC, it's deselected. If I don't have anything selected, ESC brings up the menu (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Yes, as @Rodolfo said, ESC key works just as I expected it to. I finally gave in and got Guild Wars 2 yesterday and ESC key deselects exactly as I expected it to.

Comment: I think this was changed in one of the recent patches. It didn't use to do that during bwe and stress test.

Answer (score 2):

Click on any bare part of the ground to deselect.

Edit: It was later added that the Esc key will close windows, deselect, and stop actions by default (one per click). Esc will bring up the menu if no windows are open, no target is selected, and your character is not auto-running or auto-attacking.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that doesn't answer the question. I had the same question a few days ago and that seems to be the easiest way to deselect a target.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, this is a canned comment from the review system. In addition to being fairly short and not complete compared to others answer, this answer doesn't bring anyhting that wasn  already told in another one. On this site, we prefer to avoid duplicate content.

Comment: The answers that were already stated are incorrect though. What this answer brings is conciseness and correctness. Tapan Zee's answer says how to select things and change your controls, but it does not answer the question of how to deselect things. SaintWacko's answer gives the correct method of deselection, but says that you have to turn on an option to do it, which is incorrect. Aeo's answer is based on other games and is simply incorrect.

Comment: Then, I'll admit I was wrong. If your answer is the right one, it'll be upvoted to the top anyway. Maybe I judged it a bit hastly.

Comment: @Brian Although there is rep to be had by providing your own answer, when you are only making small corrections to information provided by another answer its a good habit to simply improve their answer with an edit. Answers should be providing a variety of content, not a variety of correctness on the same content. An edit would provide just as much value with less mental processing to get there. I have to read his, then read yours, then wonder why yours has less votes, then decide which one is right, instead of simply reading his answer improved by you.